# Can Webpack load Handlebar templates?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, ghost

I have a development environment utilizing Gulp and Webpack together. The sole purpose of using Gulp is to serve up a Ghost server for theme development using ReactJS (which I have working). The purpose for Webpack is to compile and serve my dependencies for my project. As of right now, I cannot load the bundled `.js` file within my test theme. I'm curious if this is a Webpack issue by itself, that it either can't load `.hbs` files or something within my configuration is messed up.

The Ghost server loads fine, but when I switch to the theme I'm developing, the page errors out saying it can't find my bundled `.js` file with a 404. I'm thinking:

1. I *don't* have Webpack configured to serve `.hbs` files correctly.
2. I *do* have Webpack configured to serve `.hbs` files correctly, but my configuration in general is messed up.
3. This is an impossibility for Webpack at the moment

I want to load my bundled `.js` within a served `.hbs` file for a Ghost theme.

I've provided my project for an example. Just follow the super simple setup and you're good to go.

[Project link](https://github.com/eugeneross/react-ghost)

Project setup

```
My-Project
|--/gulp
   |--/dev-tasks              //individual dev gulp tasks
      |-ghost.js              //Initializes Ghost config, run's sequence of tasks for webpack-dev-server
      |-init.js               //triggers symlinking of Ghost theme
      |-sequence.js           //maps out sequence of Gulp tasks
      |-styles.js             //style compiling
      |-symlink.js            //links local theme with Ghost configuration in /node_modules/
      |-task-runner.js        //runs Gulp tasks
      |-webpack-build-dev.js  // Loads the dev compiler 
      |-webpack-build-prod.js // Not worrying about this one...
      |-webpack-dev-server.js // Runs the devServer
   |-ghost-dev-config.js      //configures Ghost environment
|--/public
   |-default.hbs
   |-index.hbs
   |-package.json
|--/src
   |--/containers
      |-App.js
      |-Home.js
      |-StyleGuide.js
      |-Uploader.js
   |--/styles
      |-main.sass
   |-router.js
|-gulpfile.js
|-package.json
|-webpack.dev.config.js
|-webpack.prod.config.js
```

Is what I'm trying to achieve just not supported by Webpack at the moment? I can get by by just using Gulp and Browserfiy, but I would love to solve this issue and make Webpack work for my needs.

Comment: The webpack dev server is intended to just provide hot-reloading for bundled assets. Processing the `.hbs` files should be done by the ghost server itself, and those templates will just point to webpack dev server URLs for the assets. That's one thing that's not very clear in webpack literature, that you don't use that as your main content server (like loading it in a browser, for example).

Comment: To put it another way, you'll want two server running in parallel; the webpack dev server and the ghost server. In your browser, you'll hit the ghost server, and the templates will point to webpack dev server URLs.

Comment: @Jacob I know exactly what you're talking about. Yes, webpack's verbiage is quite lacking. So for instance, have Ghost up on `:2368` while webpack runs on `:8080` and then within the `.hbs` templates point the assets to the webpack server (8080)? Should this, in theory, still work if I'm using React within my `.hbs` templates because React is being compiled with Webpack?

Comment: Yes, it ought to work fine.